# Cocoa/iOS Error Handling Style, without NSError

Tags: ios, cocoa, error-handling, nserror

This is a general question about handling possible errors where NSError is not being used.

Let's say we have some typical iOS/Cocoa code like this:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: myData];
```

The documentation states that an NSXMLParser object will be returned, or "nil if an error occurs".

(For the record, this particular method will happily take nil for the 'data' argument, returning a valid NSXMLParser instance.)

I have noticed that very many iOS developers never check these types of return values. They assume that the class init has always worked. That strikes me as risky, but I'd like to hear the views of seasoned/bitten Cocoa developers.

If I use NSAssert on the return value, that protects me during development, but does little for me when my app is out in the wild.

Should I check for the nil return value, and construct an NSError of my own? Or do something else?

Comment: @Bryan, that's I am asking.  How would you handle this particular error?

Comment: i will just use NSAssert to check it is not nil. if error happens, i will get nil parser and not get any work done. hopefully it is the best i can get.

Comment: @Abizern, if you google that line of code, you will find many results.  An overwhelming number of implementations are not checking for the return value. That may just be because of sample/fragment implementations, but I suspect the general approach is the same.  But if you would like to share your approach with us, I'm glad to listen.

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted here.... I thought it was a good question on a best practice. (I think the problem is Apple does not really have any, or they don't follow them, and their bugs constantly pass by QA. So Apple Fan Boi's don't know any better when following the crowd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The somewhat unwritten rule is that if an Apple init method can fail in a recoverable manner it will have an `NSError` parameter. If a method such as `NSString` fails init things are so bad that recovery really is not possible. Probably so bad that allocation an `NSError` is not possible much less an `NSLog` message. The app is probably going to crash soon no matter what you do.

Unfortunately 3rd party classes rarely follow this rule--but you should.

Comment: Thank you Zaph, for your considered, and considerate reply. I shall take your approach.